# sklearn.model_selection GridSearchCV is throwing KeyError: 'mean_train_score'

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, google-colaboratory, gridsearchcv

I am trying to fetch mean train score from `classifierobject.cv_result_` from `GridSearchCV` method using 5 fold cross-validation but it's giving me `*** KeyError: 'mean_train_score'` in Google Colab. However, the same code is running fine in local machine Ipython notebook for `sklearn` version 0.19.1. 
Can anyone help me how can I get the output in google colab?

`clf.cv_results_.keys()` ouputs following -

for my local notebook -

```
dict_keys(['mean_fit_time', 'std_fit_time', 'mean_score_time', 'std_score_time', 'param_n_neighbors', 'params', 'split0_test_score', 'split1_test_score', 'split2_test_score', 'split3_test_score', 'split4_test_score', 'mean_test_score', 'std_test_score', 'rank_test_score', 'split0_train_score', 'split1_train_score', 'split2_train_score', 'split3_train_score', 'split4_train_score', 'mean_train_score', 'std_train_score'])
```

on google colab notebook -

```
dict_keys(['mean_fit_time', 'std_fit_time', 'mean_score_time', 'std_score_time', 'param_n_neighbors', 'params', 'split0_test_score', 'split1_test_score', 'split2_test_score', 'split3_test_score', 'split4_test_score', 'mean_test_score', 'std_test_score', 'rank_test_score'])
```

where is the `mean_train_score` in google colab. Am I missing something?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
parameters = {'n_neighbors':[1, 5, 10, 15, 19 , 21, 31, 41, 51]}
clf = GridSearchCV(neigh, parameters, cv=5,\ 
                   scoring='roc_auc',n_jobs=-1) 
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
train_auc= clf.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
train_auc_std= clf.cv_results_['std_train_score']
cv_auc = clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'] 
cv_auc_std= clf.cv_results_['std_test_score']
```

Comment: can you try setting `return_train_score=True` inside `GridSearchCV()` ?

Comment: got it thanks, executed the same code in local and colab. Got confused. it got resolved now.

Comment: Happy to help, I made an answer of the comment in case anyone else hast the same problem. :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting `return_train_score=True` inside `GridSearchCV()` to calculate the train scores (are off by default, see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)). Maybe you have kind of global variable in `sklearn` somewhere local set.